# Spring use of enum constructor-arg ok in prod, not in test

Tags: java, spring, enums

We have a bean constructor in the following form:

```
<bean id="myMapper" class="com.mapper.internet.GenericMapper">
    <constructor-arg ref="service1"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="service2"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="service3"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="anotherMapper"/>
    <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="false"/>
    <constructor-arg> <value type="com.mapper.internet.AbstractGenericMapper.myType">MY_TYPE_VALUE</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This works in production, but not when we run the automated test with JUnit. The error we get is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'yetAnotherService' defined in class path resource [testBusinessApplicationContext.xml]: 
  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myLookup' while setting constructor argument; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'internetQuoteMapperLookup' defined in class path resource [testBusinessApplicationContext.xml]: 
  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'apiTimeWarnerCableEOFSymmetricQuoteMapper' 
    while setting bean property 'quoteMapperMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [API_EOF_SYMMETRIC:TIME WARNER CABLE], target type [null]]; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'apiTimeWarnerCableEOFSymmetricQuoteMapper' defined in class path resource [testBusinessApplicationContext.xml]: 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 5 of type [java.lang.String]: 
    Could not convert constructor argument value of type [com.accesspointinc.salespoint.business.quote.mapper.internet.AbstractGenericMapper$MyType] to required type [java.lang.String]: 
    Failed to convert value of type 'com.accesspointinc.salespoint.business.quote.mapper.internet.AbstractGenericMapper$MyType' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.accesspointinc.salespoint.business.quote.mapper.internet.AbstractGenericMapper$MyType] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Here are the constructors in question:

```
public EOFSymmetricQuoteMapper(Service1 service1, 
                               Service2 service2, 
                               Service3 service3, 
                               AnotherMapper revenueMapper,
                               boolean onNet,
                               String  pricingSourceString) {
    super(service1, service2, service3, revenueMapper, onNet, pricingSourceString);
}

public AbstractEOFQuoteMapper(Service1 service1, 
                              Service2 service2, 
                              Service3 service3, 
                              AnotherMapper revenueMapper,
                              boolean onAPINet,
                              String  quotePricingTypeString) {
    super(service1, service2, service3, revenueMapper);
    this.onNet = onNet;
    quotePricingType = QuotePricingType.valueOf(quotePricingTypeString);
```

The error seems straightforward enough -- we have a String in the constructor but are passing the enum type in the bean configuration. But why is it working in production and not in test -- the bean definitions are identical.

Comment: Different OS? Different Java version... Could be a bunch of things.

Comment: Which one is the constructor of `com.mapper.internet.GenericMapper` ?

Comment: Sorry -- changed some class names, but not others. There is no difference in OS or Java version between running the server under Netbeans on my machine and running the JUnit tests on my local machine.